# "incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT" on some redmine pages

Tags: utf-8, redmine

After migration of redmine 1.3.1.stable to 2.5.1.stable. All work fine exept on some of page:

**Administration / Settings** :

```
Started GET "/settings" for 80.13.99.120 at 2014-04-25 09:23:25 +0200
Processing by SettingsController#index as HTML
  Current user: bux (id=1)
  Rendered settings/_general.html.erb (6.8ms)
  Rendered settings/_display.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered common/_tabs.html.erb (14.8ms)
  Rendered settings/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (15.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20.4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
    3: <div class="box tabular settings">
    4: <p><%= setting_select :ui_theme, Redmine::Themes.themes.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, :blank => :label_default, :label => :label_theme %></p>
    5: 
    6: <p><%= setting_select :default_language, lang_options_for_select(false) %></p>
    7: 
    8: <p><%= setting_check_box :force_default_language_for_anonymous %></p>
    9: 
  app/helpers/settings_helper.rb:40:in `setting_select'
  app/views/settings/_display.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_settings__display_html_erb__360450665_108765910'
  app/views/settings/_display.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_settings__display_html_erb__360450665_108765910'
  app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_common__tabs_html_erb__1065101303_107873960'
  app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:21:in `each'
  app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_common__tabs_html_erb__1065101303_107873960'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:318:in `render_tabs'
  app/views/settings/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_settings_edit_html_erb___826014255_106971690'
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:28:in `index'
```

Same error on the user edit page, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your linux locales. Run a

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Check your locale

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
fr_FR.UTF-8... done
```

Delete your redmine cache

```
mv /path/to/redmine/tmp  /path/to/redmine/tmp_OLD
mkdir /path/to/redmine/tmp
chown youruser /path/to/redmine/tmp
```

Restart remine (and apache if using it)

Answer (score 0):

This issue discussed in Redmine bug reports [13520](http://www.redmine.org/issues/13520), [14009](http://www.redmine.org/issues/14009) and others.

The following fixed it for me on [Debian](https://debian.org):

```
apt-get install ruby-mysql2
```

then change "`adapter: mysql`" to "`adapter: mysql2`"
in "`/etc/redmine/default/database.yml`".

Comment: Or
gem install mysql2
and change
"database.yml"